# Vanilla Javascript JSON Issue

Tags: javascript, json

I have a form that when i submit it i get a JSON file that says: **{"Success":false,"Message":"This is false"}** if the form false and **{"Success":true,"Message":"This is true"}** if the form is ok.

What i would like is to write an **if statement** and say if the **JSON** file come as **true** to redirect me to page **else** redirect somewhere else. I would like to get the value of the key Success... I want to get the string that comes back which is either true or false for the key-Success. Here is the code below. The **if statement** is not working.

Javascript Code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = "POST",
  url = "that JSON file is";

  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (obj.Success == "true"){
      window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    } else {
      window.location = "http://yahoo.com";
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

What am i missing? Hopefully someone can help

Thanks.

Comment: If `Success` is either `true` or `false` then it can never be `"true"`.

Comment: thanks for ur answer @JJJ. Do you have any suggestions how to achieve what i want?

Comment: Yes. Test for `true` instead. You'll also have to test for `readyState` et al to make sure you're actually receiving the response.

Comment: i.e. just use `if (obj.Success) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The only apparent error is in this line:

```
if (obj.Success == "true") {
```

The `obj.Success` property is *already* a boolean value containing `true` or `false`, but emphatically *not* the string value `"true"`.

A corrected version would therefore be:

```
if (obj.Success === true) {
```

but since (in boolean logic) `condition === true` is just the same as writing `condition` the simplest version would just be:

```
if (obj.Success) {
```

Although not relevant to the problem, don't forget to check that the HTTP request actually succeeded in your `onreadystatechange` event handler.

Answer (score -2):

Try reworking this function a little bit. Obviously you'll need to change the URL and the object data endpoints but this worked for me.

```
function getStuff(url) {
  var xhttp, jsonData, parsedData;

  // check that we have access to XMLHttpRequest
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

     // get the data returned from the request...
     jsonData = this.responseText;
     // ...and parse it
     parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

     // return the data here
     // if the data you're returning is an object
     // you need to know the endpoints
     // for example, if there was a username,
     // you might return parsedData.username
     var success = parsedData.login;
     // debug / test
     if(success === 'RayanZenner') {
       window.location = 'https://www.google.co.uk/';
     } else {
       window.location = 'https://uk.yahoo.com/';
     }

     var elementToShowStuffIn = document.getElementById('main');
     elementToShowStuffIn.innerHTML = something;


    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

getStuff('https://api.github.com/users/RayanZenner');
```

Comment: 1) every recent browser supports `XMLHttpRequest`, 2) the OP's problem relates to their specific JSON data structure, which your answer doesn't address

Comment: But it works and all you have to do is change it to suit your needs

Comment: If the OP knew how to change it he wouldn't have asked the question.  Of the relevant parts of your answer, you've replaced the _one_ incorrect line of the OP's code with another line that _doesn't do what he needs_.